# destroy devise user session on log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When logging in a user, devise does not seem to invalidate previous sessions. If I'm logged in as UserA, return to the login screen and re-login as UserB, devise does not destroy the previous session and create a new one, but persists the UserA session. I'm wondering how I can call Session#destroy on user login. I know I could re-implement the Session#create method but from what I understand, that would involve generating all the controller views. I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to invalidate UserA session when UserB logs in you might have problems when they log in from different places.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extreme edge case. UserA signs in then he signs in as UserB without signing out isn't going to happen often. If you are really worried about it, you can redirect to the main page of the site with flash message "Already signed in." or something like that.

Comment: I don't see this as an "extreme edge case" at all - rather, it's a question of application design, and I've seen it plenty of times. Public-facing pages that include a login form are a good example, because there may not be any functionality specific to a logged-in user, and therefore no cue to indicate the user is already logged in. You could argue that the user "should" log out first, but a developer has no direct control over user behaviour. The fact that someone is entering login details in the first place should be an implicit "logout" of any existing sessions in my opinion.